# ASP.NET Core authentication - AuthenticateAsync() vs User

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, middleware

I've stumbled upon such code multiple times (e.g. in some controller actions):

```html
var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync();
if (result.Succeeded)
{
  // Get authenticated user's principal
  var user = result.Principal;
}
```

What is the benefit of calling `AuthenticateAsync()` directly if we can access current user this way, after the authentication middleware validated the cookie on request and signed user in?

```html
if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
  // Get authenticated user's principal
  var user = HttpContext.User;
}
```

Comment: It means whoever wrote the code originally didn't understand what they were doing.

Comment: _"What is the benefit of calling `AuthenticateAsync()` directly"_ - assuming _nothing funny_ is going on (e.g. Kerberos/Integrated auth, etc) then there is no benefit.

Comment: `AuthenticateAsync` and `AuthorizeAsync` are different methods for different things.

Comment: `AuthenticateAsync` returns more properties than just `Principal`, so it can be useful if you want to look at `Properties` or `Ticket`. If the code only uses the `Principal` property, using `HttpContext.User` is effectively the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

An authentication scheme's authenticate action is responsible for constructing the user's identity based on request context. It returns an AuthenticateResult indicating whether authentication was successful and, if so, the user's identity in an authentication ticket.

You could check this [doucment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) related,and the [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.authenticateasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0) of authenticateasync method